# Not certain what is wrong with my simple SQL Queries that use joins?

Tags: sql-server, join

Unfortunately, I am brand new to SQL and am using SQL Server to create very simple queries, but I am having issues that I am not exactly certain how to work around...

For the first one, I have to comment out the date in order for it to work, otherwise everything is blank...

```
SELECT 
    VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
FROM 
    Vendors 
JOIN 
    Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
WHERE 
    InvoiceDate < 6/1/2008 
ORDER BY 
    VendorName;
```

The 2nd one has an extra column that I am not sure how to get rid of.

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber, VendorName, InvoiceDate
FROM 
    Vendors AS v 
JOIN 
    Invoices AS i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
WHERE 
    InvoiceTotal > 0;
```

And lastly, This one (my other queries work fine) is not working. It is supposed to be joining 3 tables and filtering the results by `VendorID` sorting by `VendorName`, then I keep getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '115, 122, 123' to data type int.

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceDate, VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM
    Vendors
JOIN 
    Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
JOIN 
    InvoiceLineItems ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
WHERE 
    Vendors.VendorID = '115, 122, 123'
ORDER BY 
    VendorName;
```

If anyone can please offer any suggestions, it would be much appreciated, thank you...

Comment: 1. Try this for your date: `'2008-06-01'` (that is 1st of June) 2. Whats the extra column called? How many do you see and how many do you want? I would expect 3 columns. How are we to know which one you don't want?. Lastly use `IN (115,122,123)`

Comment: Hm, I still have the same issue with the date (I tried that format earlier) and I am not seeing the extra column now? My mistake, I apologize. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you have a time component in your data. Try `BETWEEN '2008-05-29' AND '2008-06-02'`. Do you see anything? Try removing it altogether. Do you see anything?

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes, I tried that and still nothing unless I comment it out. I think it might be these (required) data files that I downloaded for the assignments, so not your fault. Sometimes they are out-dated or off. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: When you comment it out what do the dates look like when they come back? post a sample. What datatype is the column `InvoiceDate`. Most assignment questions we get on here don't function it's quite disappointing.

Comment: The invoice dates only start at '2012-03-05 00:00:00'  and no date goes past 2012. IIRC, if the date does not exist, it will be empty, right?

Comment: Correct. Your `WHERE` clause causes it to return no rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date comparison should be like below with quotes. It'd match your date db format

```
WHERE InvoiceDate < '6/1/2008'
```

To check item between range it'd be in below format

```
Vendors.VendorID IN (115, 122, 123)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE Vendors.VendorID = '115, 122, 123'
```

The correct syntax is `IN(value,value...)` for multiple items in a `where` clause.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Comment: And the problem with your first query is that the date literal ought to be in single quotes.